# How can i refer to indexPath in UILabel and UIButton collection?

Tags: arrays, uilabel

```
var index = buttons.index(of: sender)

label[index!].backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
```

How can i make the other buttons white. İ mean i want to choose all elements ecxept `[index]` in the `[UILabel]` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this without using an index:

```
for label in labelArray {
        if (label != sender) {
            // label.setNewColor...
        }
    }
```